# Get all input id values from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a form with some input text. Each of them have a specific ID that i have to retrieve in order to make specific treatment.

For this i created a basic JavaScript that is querying the whole HTML document.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var inputs = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
        console.log(input.getElementsByTagName('id'));
        inputs.push(this);
    });

    console.log(inputs);
})
```

At this stage i just try to get them all in a console and push the id's into an array. I'll add them to an array or something else. 
My issue is that I obtain empty HTMLCollection with an error message

TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (:2:14)

Comment: If you use `.getAttribute('id')` instead `.getElementsByTagName('id')` should work

Comment: Or just `input.id`. The `getElementsByTagName()` doesn't make sense

Comment: getAttribute did it fine. I didn't write a line of javaScript for decade...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the *id* attribute before pushing that into the array.

**Please Note:** [Arrow function (=>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not have it's own `this`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var inputs = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
    //console.log(this.constructor.name); // Window
    if(input.id)
     inputs.push(input.id);
  });
  console.log(inputs);
})
```

```html
<input id="abc"/>
<input id="xyz"/>
<input />
```